# Restrict Action in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to restrict the action to not to be called if it has the required parameter available in the url. for example I have a Login Action ut it only be access with it hit on an other web application and it redirect with query string parameter. but it can also be accessible with out parameter I want to restrict this.

### Ristrict it

```
https://localhost:44300/account/login
```

### Right Url

```
https://localhost:44300/Account/Login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdevatea.portal.azure-api.net%2F%2F
```

Comment: MVC action filters !

Comment: What is the desired action when the parameter doesn't exist?  Should it return a 404 error, a 500 error, redirect somewhere or something else?

Comment: when parameter does not exist it execute the login action but I want this action only be accessible by redirecting to this page by other web app not directly. because when other app redirect the user to login page it return some query string which is important

Comment: when parameter not exist then it shows 404 eror page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I think the easiest way would be to just add a check to the login action and return a 404 Not Found if the returnUrl is empty or null.

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) return HttpNotFound();

    //remaining code for login
    //...

}
```